# Does SQL Server Management Studio have two simultaneous versions?

Tags: ssms

SQL Server Management Studio: It's version 18.12.1. No! It's version 15.0.18424.0! At least, my installation of SSMS is showing me both, as shown below in the dialog capture. To what, more specifically, does each of the two versions apply?

[image: screen capture of the "About SQL Server Management Studio" dialog box from SSMS reading "SQL Server Management Studio v 18.12.1" at the top, with a table of components underneath. The first data row of the table gives "SQL Server Management Studio" as a component name and 15.0.18424.0 as its version.]

Comment: That's SSMS, not SQL Server. And one is the build number, one the version number. (Though it seems in SSMS 19 Microsoft have aligned these better.)

Comment: I'm not sure why users are voting to migrate this to [dba.se]; there's nothing in the question about database administration, it's about SSMS. Nothing in their [on-topic](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) article is related to what's being asked here.

Comment: @Larnu, I did write "SSMS" in the body, I'd been sloppy in the title, but I see Mark Rotteveel fixed it.

Comment: A lot of people seem to think that SSMS and SQL Server are synonyms hence the comment. Using the names interchangeably is both incorrect and confusing. Fortunately here, due to the image, it was clear you meant SSMS, *not* SQL Server.

Comment: @Larnu, your explanation makes sense. I wonder whether there's an easy way to convey to Microsoft that they ought to replace "Versions" with "Builds" as the column header to prevent confusion. :)

Comment: Well, as I mentioned, in SSMS 19 it looks like they're "addressed" the issue, as the "version number" displayed in the above dialogue window also starts with 19. I *suspect* that the number above is a "hangover" from when SSMS and SQL Server were shipped in one install; then SSMS and SQL Server both used year name releases, and also had the same major version. It seems that Microsoft continued to use the old version numbers in the above dialogue, even though they switched to calling it "SSMS 16" (which didn't mean 2016) with SQL Server 2016.

Comment: SSMS 18 was released alongside SQL Server 2019, which was version 15 of the data engine, and hence why SSMS 18 has 15 above; as Microsoft hadn't change the underlying version number. As mentioned, however, for SSMS 19 (which was released alongside SQL Server 2022) shows 19 in both things like the splash screen and the help dialogue window.

Comment: SSMS Versions and Build Numbers: https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/2018/01/sql-server-management-studio-ssms.html